# Using cURL with PHP to get the HTML of a website. How do I get all of it?

Tags: php, curl

I'm using a library that parses HTML for particular data. It also offers a convenient `fetch` function. However, it has a weird line that I don't understand. Here's the code:

```
function fetch($url, &$curlInfo=null) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 5);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = $curlInfo = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    if (strpos(strtolower($info['content_type']), 'html') === false) {
        // The content was not delivered as HTML, do not attempt to parse it.
        return null;
    }

    $html = mb_substr($response, $info['header_size']);
    return parse($html, $url);
}
```

The penultimate line currently ends up chopping off the first *n* bites of the actual HTML. Has cURL changed behavior since this was first written?

Whats the correct way to use cURL to get the HTML of a website?

Comment: You might want to look up what `CURLOPT_HEADER` does …

Comment: @mario: in trying to debug this I've added a var_dump($html) before the return parse(). The start of the HTML has already been stripped.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe, so I either need to set `CURLOPT_HEADER` to 1, which would then be stripped by the `mb_substr` line, or just not perform the substitution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CURLOPT_HEADER` determines whether or not the HTTP headers will be included in the output of `curl_exec`.

Since you have set it to `0`, they will not – yet you are cutting of a number of characters according to the size of the headers of the content.

Comment: Indeed, removing the line that manually cuts off the fist *n* bytes makes everything work as it should.